# How to add custom background color in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I want to add custom background color for canvas

how to add custom color to oracle forms developer

Comment: Do you want to change the color during runtime?

Comment: i added color code r100g100b100 but i need calculator background color like in windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click your canvas, and select "Property Palette":
[image]

Then, set the property "Background" as you wish (you can use sintax like `r70g85b85` or `red`, for example).

Comment: i added color code r100g100b100 but i need calculator background color like in windows 7

Comment: Click on button "..." next on background field, and verify if you can find the color you're looking for. Oracle forms colors are very limited, so there is a chance that you will not be able to use the color you want

Answer (score 2):

Define a Visual attribute namely `myGrayBack` with your desired background color ( 
may be `gray4`  ) code with from toolbar.

[image]

In `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` or `PRE-FORM` trigger's code, add the following :

```
SET_CANVAS_PROPERTY('CANVAS1', visual_attribute, 'myGrayBack');
```

Comment: Probably he should choose a more generic name, in case one day they want it blue ;)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson sure, an interesting style :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Canvas' Property Palette window and set its "Background Color" property to some color.

Comment: i added color code r100g100b100 but i need calculator background color like in windows 7

Comment: Create an item which will contain your RGB values and a button. In WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger, use SET_CANVAS_PROPERTY built-in and set its BACKGROUND_PROPERTY to the item value.

Comment: but i want without trigger